# Someone please explain thisquery events I am having difficulty with

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur, onfocus

I am really new to javascript / jquery and am having a difficult time understanding the following:

I load my scripts in the head section of my page.

I have an input form somewhat like this ...

```
<input id='registeremail' type='email; name='email' onblur=checkemail() >

<button id='btn1'>Hello</button>
```

In the above scenario I have, as noted in my head section the following which DOES NOT WORK.

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){

   function checkemail() {
       checkthis = $('#registeremail').val();
        $('#btn1').text(checkthis);
   }

   });

</script>
```

The ONLY way I can get it to works is like this

Keep input form just like above

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

   $('#registeremail').focusout( function() {
      checkthis = $('#registeremail').val();
      $('#btn1').text(checkthis);

   });

</script>
```

This is driving me nuts. is onblur not compatible with jquery? What is the obvious thing I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: because you put the function in a document ready, it is not in global scope. And Java is different than JavaScript.

Comment: `onblur=checkemail()` - should be `onblur="checkemail()"`. Mistype here or in your code?

Comment: You have typo here `type='email;` it should be `type='email'`

Comment: `onblur` is compatible with jQuery. There's even a [shorthand function](https://api.jquery.com/blur/).

Comment: @CynePhoba12 That's actually valid HTML. The quotes are optional when the value doesn't contain a space. (though yes, there's a typo on `email`)

Comment: add a var/const to checkthis = $('#registeremail').val();

Answer (score 1):

Names that are used in `onXXX` attributes are looked up in the global scope. You have your function inside `$(document).ready()`, so the function name is only available inside that scope, not in global scope.

There's no general need to put function definitions inside `$(document).ready()`. That's only needed for code that shouldn't run until after the document is loaded. Function definitions don't run immediately, they just save the definition. You can put function definitions in there if they're only used by other functions in the `$(document).read()`, to avoid polluting the global scope. But if you want to all the function from the global scope, you need to take it out.

Also, get in the habit of putting quotes around attribute values. It's only strictly needed if the value contains certain special characters (such as space or `>`), but it's good idea in general.

```
onblur='checkemail()'
```